# MongoDB replication error NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit and MaxTimeMSExpired - Causes and Fix

Tags: mongodb, replication

In a replication set up of primary, secondary and arbiter, the replication connection URI times out intermittently and logs show below error. Please help share what could be the issue and what would be the recommended fix for same.

```
 NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit: error in fetcher batch callback ::
caused by :: timed out. Last fetched optime (with hash): { ts:
Timestamp(1554364591, 71), t: 65596 }[3697357721798898959]. Restarts
remaining: 1 I REPL     [replication-1] Error returned from oplog
query (no more query restarts left): MaxTimeMSExpired: error in
fetcher batch callback :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit W
REPL     [rsBackgroundSync] Fetcher stopped querying remote oplog with
error: MaxTimeMSExpired: error in fetcher batch callback :: caused by
:: operation exceeded time limit I REPL     [SyncSourceFeedback]
SyncSourceFeedback error sending update to <ServerFQDN>:27017:
InvalidSyncSource: Sync source was cleared. Was <ServerFQDN>:27017`

I did refer to link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798577/mongodb-replication-timeout

but it does not match the case with ours. The disk drives have enough space. Please help suggest what could be wrong here. Thank you!!

Each time restart the mongo service on both the servers but it does not help. Error keeps coming intermittently.
```

Comment: Please check what is the value of `rs.status()` when you are getting the Timeout error.

Comment: rs.status() shows state of servers as healthy i.e. Primary, Secondary and Arbiter. However, if we try to run show dbs, the shell does not respond back.

Comment: did you succeeded to solve this?